# If $X =V(x^{2}+y^{2}-1, x-1)$, what is $I(V)$? Here $V$ is affine variety and $I(V)$ its ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry

As we can remove $x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)$ then we have $I(V)=(x-1,y^2)$.

Could someone check whether it correct?

Comment: What do you call $V$ and what do you call $I$?

Comment: @PackSciences $V$ is the set of all points such that both polynomials vanish, $I$ is the ideal (set with some structure) of all poynomials that vanish on the set of points.

Comment: @Metso what is your ambient space

Comment: @Prince M: The exercise is described so. No more info.

Comment: Are you typically over $\mathbb{C}$? Have they introduced Hilberts Nullstellensatz?

Comment: @Prince M: Not yet, it's the next chapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly the second polynomial implies $x = 1$, sub this into the first polynomial so that $y = 0$. The only point in the variety is $(1,0) \in k^2$.

The ideal of polynomials vanishing on this point is $\langle x-1, y \rangle$. You can prove that $$I(\{ \, (1,0) \, \} ) = \langle x-1, y \rangle $$ by using the definition of $I$,

$$I(\{ \, (1,0) \, \} ) = \{ \, f(x,y) \in k[x,y] \, |  \, f(1,0) = 0 \, \},$$

and showing containment in both directions. One direction is trivial, the other direction is a generalization of the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Comment: You don't need Nullstellensatz for this exercise, but it is immediate if you already know what Nullstellensatz says :)